# Polygon of convex arcs

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, convexity

Convex polygons in the plane $R^2$ arise in linear programming where the constraints are linear. The objective linear function attains its maximum at a vertex of the feasible region(if exists).
Assume that the constraints are presented by convex functions instead of linear ones. In this case, the feasible region if exists will be a region bounded by convex arcs(maybe line segments also). For example the conditions $y-x^2\le 5$ and $100x-(y-2)^2\le 100$ for non-negative values of $x,y$ gives such region as shown in the following figure.
[image]
**My Question**
Is there any study of such regions as generalized polygons considering its area, convexity, starshapedness, supporting lines and so on? I failed to find one using many keywords. So, if the answer is yes, please I need a reference and keywords if possible.
If the answer is no, do you think a study of these polygons is significant enough to consider as a research topic?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP: "please I need a reference and keywords if possible."
There is literature that goes under the names "circular-arc polygons"
and "conic-arc polygons."

> Berberich, Eric, Arno Eigenwillig, Michael Hemmer, Susan Hert, Kurt Mehlhorn, and Elmar Schömer. "A computational basis for conic arcs and boolean operations on conic polygons." In *European Symposium on Algorithms*, pp. 174-186. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2002.
>   [Springer link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45749-6_19)
>   
>             
>   [image: Fig1]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Fig.1: The union of two curved polygons. Berberich et al.</sup>

---

> Moore, Antoni, Chris Mason, Peter A. Whigham, and Michelle Thompson-Fawcett. "Polygon Generalization with Circle Arcs." In *GSR*. 2012.
>   [PDF download](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6b64/419ecbf411fb25563f2f4c6719741e5dfbd5.pdf).
>
> Wang, Zhi Jie, Xiao Lin, Bin Yao, Yong-Xi Gong, and Mei-E. Fang. "An Efficient Algorithm for Boolean Operation on Circular-arc Polygons."  [arXiv:1211.0729](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0729). (2012).
>
> Aurenhammer, Franz, and Bert Jüttler. "On computing the convex hull of (piecewise) curved objects." *Mathematics in computer science* 6, no. 3 (2012): 261-266. [Author PDF download](http://www.industrial-geometry.at/uploads/fsp_report_63.pdf).
>   
>             
>   [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Aurenhammer & Jüttler.</sup>
>
> Chernov, N., Yu Stoyan, Tatiana Romanova, and Aleksandr Pankratov. "Phi-functions for 2D objects formed by line segments and circular arcs." *Advances in Operations Research* 2012 (2012).
>   
>             
>   [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Fig.1, Chernov, Romanova, Pankratov.</sup>

---